# How to get EXTJS 4 inside the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, extjs, extjs4, asset-pipeline

I recently started working with Rails 3.1. It's a very nice framework
and I like the 'asset pipeline' philosophy. Adding libraries that exist 
of one file is quite easy and works out of the box. However, adding a library 
which exists of a folder like EXTJS 4 is somewhat more difficult.

I'd like to just add the whole EXTJS4 folder to the '/app/assets' folder
And do a //= require_tree in my 'application.js' file but that does not 
include the css files. Also images and scss files are not included this way.
All the images/css files are referenced 'relatively' from the js file so 
I think the folder structure should be maintained as it is.

What is the best and easiest way to add this library to my rails projects?
I dont want to specify the whole list of EXTJS resources to my view each time
I create a new view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply leaving the Ext library (linked) inside of "public" works just fine.

One caveat here: keep in mind, that if you want sprockets to not interfere, then, while using Rails view helpers, you need the paths to your extjs JS and CSS files to be absolute, e.g. starting with "/". Let's say we have the Ext library in "public/extjs". Then these 2 calls will be needed in your Rails view/layout:

```
javascript_include_tag "/extjs/ext-all-debug"
stylesheet_link_tag "/extjs/resources/css/ext-all"
```

Comment: Ok, it's now in the 'public' folder. Which files should be included in my view? It's still not working.... I can imagine it works like this but things are not bundled with sprocket like this I think. If everything is precompiled and put together with sprockets it is probably also a lot faster in production.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some caveat I remember having when switching to Rails 3.1. Not sure about performance - maybe someone else can comment.